# ViewPager2 changes fragment when selecting EditText

Tags: java, android

I'm using a `ViewPager2` with 3 fragments (A, B and C).
`Fragment` A and C contain an `EditText`.
When selecting the `EditText` in fragment C, the `ViewPager` switches back to fragment A with focus on the `EditText` in fragment A (keyboard opens).
Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Comment: Without some code, we can't know that behavior. Maybe did you set a tabIndex?

Comment: same here , any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi mreza sh, I did not manage to change this behavior. I switched to the 'old' ViewPager, which does not have this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug I have exactly the same issue, if you want to continue to use `ViewPager2` you need to remove `setOffscreenPageLimit();` on your viewPager, but your fragments not be retained and not being created during the viewPager implementation

Comment: This bug is fixed starting from Version 1.0.0-beta04 of ViewPager2: Fix for EditText with certain attribute configurations causing a scroll/page jump on typing/focus. (b/138044582, b/139432498)